# Nest thermostats wiring problem 3 storey house (3rd gen, E, analogue one)

Tags: wiring, thermostat

My house has 3 storeys and 3 thermostats. 2nd and 3rd floor have nest e and nest thermostats respectively. The 1st floor has an old analogue one that used to work ok. After the nest upgrade I noticed that the boiler was working, even though I did not give the order to the thermostats but I believed that there was something wrong with the settings of the nest app (pre heat, schedule etc). But this was happening even in "off" state.After a pump fix I noticed that the 1st floor radiators were hot even though the thermostat was also off. The 2nd and 3rd nest thermostats work as expected. Could it be a compatibility problem or a wrong wiring by myself?

[image: 2nd floor]
[image: 3rd floor]

[image: old thermostat wiring]
[image: nest 3rd gen thermostat wiring]

Comment: This should be migrated to [Home Improvement.SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to homeimprovement.SE

Comment: Too old to do that (1 month)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything else, I can tell you that your jumper is suspicious: on the thermostat (middle photo) it goes from the *red* wire on terminal Y1 to L4; whereas, on your Heatlink, you've got it going from the *black* wire on L to someplace else (terminal 2).

Now, I happen to have just been looking things up about Nest, and one thing they say is, "You won't need any jumpers".  So that's suspicious as well.  Could be that doesn't apply to the Heat Link, but I'm a little doubtful.

I recommend you download the installation manual ([here's a UK example](https://nest.com/support/images/misc-assets/Nest-Thermostat-Installation-Guide-UK.pdf), you may need to find a US one, if that's where you are).  It says (p25) terminal 2 is Common and 3 is Call for Heat.  Also, website [nestwiring.com](https://nestwiringdiagram.com/) seems to have a ton of diagrams, maybe you'll find one that applies.  If you take those and get the diagrams for your heating unit, and look at them side by side, you ought to be able to figure it out.